# Edit and update a joined queries

Tags: sql, delphi, join, edit

I have four tables FDQueries (Firebird 3.0) COUNTRIES, REGIONS, DEPARTMENTS, AND CITIES and a fifth temporay FDQuery where to display CITIES table with related data from others tables as following :

```
SELECT C.NAMEXXX AS NAMEXXX, D.NAMEXXX as NAMEXXX, R.NAMEXXX AS NAMEXXX, T.NAMEXXX AS NAMEXXX
FROM GEOCITI C
LEFT JOIN GEODEPT D ON D.PKINDEX = C.FKDEPAR
LEFT JOIN GEOREGI R ON R.PKINDEX=D.FKREGIO
LEFT JOIN GEOCOUN T ON T.PKINDEX=R.FKCOUNT
```

The join is working perfectly and showing what i want :

Now this done, i want the user to edit the CITIES table directly from the Grid showing the joined table (Temporary) My question is how to do this the right way to update with a simple post only original CITIES Table

Thanks and sorry for my first question formulation

Comment: I know what you did in your previous post, but nobody else here would. When you post a question you need to provide a "Minimal, Reproducible Example". You also need to try yourself and post what you tried and where you got stuck. Stackoverflow is not a coding service and you won't learn if you don't give it a try yourself.

Comment: There's too many possibilities here. It depends what Dataset descendents you are using and what database and so on. You need to show us something of what you've done so far.

Comment: I've had very bad experience using database components of any kind to modify joined SQL queries. Better to take some more control, and either execute update scripts manually, or use separate query components for each table, just so I have my own clarity on what's actually happening.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following query to update table using join -

```
UPDATE CITIES
SET CITYPOPULATION = YOUR_UPDATED_VALUE
FROM CITIES C
JOIN DEPARTMENTS D ON C.departmentname = D.NAME
JOIN COUNTRIES CT ON D.countryname = CT.name;
```

You can read [this](https://www.elevatesoft.com/manual?action=viewtopic&id=dbisam4&product=delphi&version=7&topic=update_statement) article for further update.